# Can I remove /usr/local/ysqld.local.err file from my macbook?

Tags: mysql, macos

I am using a macbook Air with the macOS Mojave system. I find that lately the "stystem" has been taking up most 0f my storage (90+GB out of 128 GB), so I used the OmniDiskSweeper to locate huge files. I found that the following file: usr/local/mysql-8/0/14-acos10.14-x86_64/data/mysqld.local.err is the biggest file taking up the space (63 GB).

I wonder can I remove this file safe without messing up with the system? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can delete it.
It conatains the error log and will be created automatically

What you also can do is run

```
FLUSH GENERAL LOGS
```

As daily event for example or manually, when you nnat to start the error log file a new.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-error-logs

or you sto the error log completely, if you don't need it at the time

By editing the my.cnf file

and delete the file name

```
log-error=
```

and restart then the server new

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I gain 60+GB after deleting the log!

Comment: err log file takes a lot of space in mac. It's hard to manage where space going
Now I am also going to delete the file. Thanks.

Comment: simply flush it regularly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-rotation.html

Comment: @nbk with all the services that might run, why aren't there sane defaults for this. 12GB here, and the file was catching dust, since I renamed my hostname a while back, what a mess.